# Camel Restlet Response to Bean or Model Class

Tags: apache-camel, restlet

I need camel restlet from another restlet to a class object . But i am getting

> org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream@12a7889

in producerTemplate .

Invoking camel :

```
Future<Object> responseFuture = producer.asyncRequestBody("direct:fablertcatalogredirect", k1);
            try {
                Object obj = (Object)responseFuture.get(500, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    System.out.println("Future Output Value"+obj.toString());
                    System.out.println("Bytes : "+obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods());
            System.out.println(obj.getClass());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My RouteBuilder:

```
from("direct:fablertcatalogredirect").to("http://localhost:8093/FablertsCatalog/getresults");
```

If I ran this using postman rest client I can get the JSON . But here I am getting `org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream` as response.

Answer (score 0):

i had to something like this in the route after the http call

.convertBodyTo(String.class)